# What is the parametric value t' for an ellipse that corresponds to the same angle t in an inscribed circle?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a unit circle centered at the origin defined parametrically as 
$$
x = \cos \ t,\  y = \sin \ t
$$
and an ellipse centered at the origin defined parametrically as
$$
x = a\cdot \cos \ t^\prime,\  y = b\cdot \sin \ t^\prime
$$
I need to find a formula to convert from $t$ to $t^\prime$.

I want to be able to draw an arc on the circle given $t_1$ and $t_2$ and draw the corresponding arc (using $t^\prime_1$ and $t^\prime_2$) on the ellipse so that I can draw a straight line from the origin that touches an endpoint of the arc on the circle and the corresponding endpoint on the ellipse.

Comment: You could use two-argument arctangent for the purpose, I suppose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$g(r) := \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + r \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos t \\ \sin t \end{pmatrix}$$

the straight line connecting the origine and the pont $(\cos t,\sin t)$ on the unit circle. There exists exactly one intersecting point of this line and the ellipse, i.e.

$$g(r) = \begin{pmatrix} a \cdot \cos x \\ b \cdot \sin x \end{pmatrix}$$

for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in [0,2\pi]$. Hence by definition of $g$:

$$r \cdot \cos t = a \cdot \cos x, r \cdot \sin t = b \cdot \sin x \\
\Rightarrow r=a \cdot \frac{\cos x}{\cos t} = b \cdot \frac{\sin x}{\sin t} \\
\Rightarrow a \cdot \tan t = b \cdot \tan x \\
\Rightarrow x = \arctan \left( \frac{a}{b} \cdot \tan t \right)$$

Comment: Thanks! What is the value of $x$ at $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: If $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\cos t =0$, thus $\cos x \stackrel{!}{=}0$ and therefore $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$.